# Why is the return not returning anything? (closed)

Tags: python, return, return-value

I'm new to Python and learning about the return statement.
But when I run this code, it doesn't return anything.

```
def string_times(str, n):
    return str*n

string_times("Hi", 5)
```

I've already tried to run this in IDLE and VS Code but it didn't work in either.

Comment: You mean it doesn't *print* anything? Try `print(string_times("Hi", 5))`

Comment: You probably want to `print` the return value

Comment: The behavior of automatically writing the value of an expression to standard output is a property of the REPL, not Python itself.

Comment: Terminology note, `return` is not a function, it is a statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code actually is returning something, but you are not outputting anything to the screen.
Simply wrap your function call in a print statement, and it should work:`print(string_times("Hi", 5))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to print it explicitly, use `print(string_times("Hi, 5))` instead of `string_times("Hi", 5)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the output I would suggest using print() function.
There is nothing wrong with your code the function works fine.

```
def string_times(str, n):
    return str*n

print(string_times("Hi", 5))
```